# Ignore some self-defined command during compilation?

Tags: macros, compiling

In a .tex file, there is some self defined command

```
\newcommand{\mycomment}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}}
...
\mycomment{blah blah}
...
```

I hope to be able to skip the command during compilation in my final version, but still compile it in versions before my final version. Are there any ways to do that?

Comment: do you just mean change to `\newcommand{\mycomment}[1]{}` for the final version? Or something else?

Comment: @David: In the final version, `\mycomment{blah blah}` will be ignored during compilation.

Comment: The definition I suggested in the first comment does that, it defines the command to take the argument and do nothing with it

Answer (score 4):

```
\newif\iffinal
\newcommand{\mycomment}[1]{\iffinal\else\textcolor{red}{#1}\fi}
...
\mycomment{blah blah}
```

And you have Boolean values `\finaltrue` and `\finalfalse`. For development versions set `\finalfalse` somewhere in the preamble *after* `\newif\iffinal`, for the final compilation set `\finaltrue`, or set both and comment out the inactive Boolean:

```
\finalfalse
% \finaltrue
```

Comment: BTW I find the bools or toggles from `etoolbox` much more convenient.

Answer (score 4):

Another fairly intuitive method, particularly if you have several large blocks of code which you want to include in some compilations but not others is the comment package (also saves a lot of time if you are writing a very large manuscript, but only working on a small bit at a time). However its great for small toggles too.

```
\usepackage{comment}
 %switches    
\excludecomment{versiona}
\excludecomment{versionb}
\includecomment{versionx}

..

\begin{versiona}
\newcommand{\mycomment}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}
etc
\end{versiona}

\begin{versionb}
\newcommand{\mycomment}[1]{\textcolor{red}{#1}
etc
\end{versionb}
```